# meteorJS + mouse/touch events on mobile - how best to listen for events?

Tags: javascript, touch, meteor

What is the best event to respond to for simple clicks on mobile web apps?

mousedown doesn't work for ios, and neither did touchstart for me.
(and neither now does a 'click' event it seems wtf?)
android has no problems. 
I'm testing in apple's simulator hopefully it simulates these properly, but it just blinks at me with nothing in the attached console (via safari)

so according to this:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/6320acabc46bd6832d2f6db943b69a0634d6b6f9/packages/fastclick

> If you would like to use Fastclick for mobile web as well, add it to
>   your app directly with meteor add fastclick.

which I've done. And it should [do the setup for me attaching to body etc.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/6320acabc46bd6832d2f6db943b69a0634d6b6f9/packages/fastclick/post.js#L7)

However I don't get any response on a click event (oh, sometimes. maybe the ios simulator is buggy?)

Is fastclick better than hammer or other solutions?

Do i need to attach the events myself with jquery or should they just "work better" as default meteor 'click' events without the ugly delay?

It's surprising this isn't more clear for meteor + mobile, but I can't see [anything in the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) on it.

Answer (score 4):

I personally love fastclick. It works straight out of the box with the regular 'click' event. just add the package

```
meteor add fastclick
```

and your click events will no longer have lag!